# Overlay appear above a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, overlay

I've been hunting around the internet for an example of a button that when clicked will make an overlay appear directly above the button.  Meaning that an overlay box bottom will line up with the top of the button.  Just wondering if anyone has an example of this?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at this? or maybe a jsfiddle.net where you get some thing similar?

Comment: You have to try and replicate the problem with stack snippet to make it easier on those that may want to help.

Comment: I don't understand the desired behaviour... are you looking for a tooltip like http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips or popover like http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Please put more effort in your question. I'm sure you read about tooltips if you have "hunted around the internet". How is your problem different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being so general on my question.  The following is some code I did to get a positive result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setVisibility(id) {
        if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer'){
          document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }else{
          document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

        #container {
            width:1px;
            height:1px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #nav,
        #data {
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            bottom:100%; /* change to TOP and it will drop down */
            background: #fff;
        }

        #data{
            z-index: 10;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test text</p>
    <p>test text</p>
    <p>test text</p>
    <p>test text</p>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="data" >
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Hide Layer'
       onclick="setVisibility('data')";>
    <script> setVisibility('data'); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer (solving your problem) or what you've tried? If the latter, include it in your question, don't post an answer.